# Using Driftbot in a single page React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, drift

I am using Driftbot, [See Here](https://help.drift.com/getting-started/installing-drift-on-a-react-app)
and am trying to get it to enable/disable based on the current route/url. I AM USING REACT-ROUTER.

I am able to use `drift.unload()` to stop it from running (in my `componentWillMount()` function) but am unable to get it started back up again.

We have some code that was pulled from here on SO that has been working, except we now need to modify it such that it is disabled on specific pages.

Here is the code we are currently using:

```
let driftbot_function = function() {
      !function() {
        var t;
        if (t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [], !t.init) return t.invoked ? void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice.")) : (t.invoked = !0,
        t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on"],
        t.factory = function(e) {
          return function() {
            var n;
            return n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
          };
        }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
          t[e] = t.factory(e);
        }), t.load = function(t) {
          var e, n, o, i;
          e = 3e5, i = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script"),
          o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + i + "/" + t + ".js",
          n = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], n.parentNode.insertBefore(o, n);
        });
      }();

      drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
      drift.load('****__our-key__****');
      drift.page();
    }

    driftbot_function();
```

This is currently in the `componentDidMount()` of our `app.js` since it is our root `'/'`. I have also tried moving this over inside a script tag in `index.html` but had the same results.

When linking to a part of the app I want it disabled, the only method that will disable it is `window.drift.unload()`. `.hide` and `.off` will not work.

When going back to the root, I have the command, `window.drift.load()`, but now it is an empty function, where before running the `unload()` function it was working.

I have also tried including the functions found in the Drift Docs linked above in both my `root.js` and `app.js` files to no avail

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How is navigation handled in your app? Do you use React Router, or some equivalent?

Comment: So sorry, yes. I am using react-router. I totally forgot to include that in my post. That is what is causing the issue. I am able to "blacklist" various URLS in the settings tab of the Drift Dashboard but it only takes effect on a page refresh which obviously wont work

Comment: For anyone needing a quick fix for this. You can use `drift.show()` and `drift.hide()` to show/hide the message icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a very confusing ride but I finally figured it out with the help of some of the engineers over at drift.

First of all, in the settings of their dash when you "blacklist" urls you need to only include keywords not full URLs (my first mistake).

Secondly, put the fucntion in a script in the `index.html` file

Thirdly, find all of the top-level route components where you want the widget to be disabled and include the following code like in their react article

```
componentWillMount() {
  drift.page(this.props.location.pathname)
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname) {
    drift.page(nextProps.location.pathname)
  }
}
```

This will basically re-initialize the widget and run a `.includes` check from your provided url (`this.props.location.pathname`) against the keywords in your settings blacklist. It will then disable it or enable it depending on the results.

There you go, good luck to anyone else stuck on this...

Comment: Are you importing `drift` somewhere? How is drift not undefined when using it in a component?

Answer (score 1):

drift.page() was not working for me

i am using the npm package for react
https://github.com/chardmd/react-drift
drift is included in one of my top level components

```
   <Drift appId='123456789' />
    <Favicon url={this.favicon} />
    <Meta
      meta={this.state.data.metaTags}
    />
```

routes rules are set then set as normal in the drift UI

```
   componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {

const prevLoc = prevProps.location.pathname
const newLoc = this.props.location.pathname

if (prevLoc !== newLoc) {
 window.drift.reset()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options for your case. First would be to create a component only for starting/stopping driftbot. You would initialise driftbot on `componentDidMount` then call `window.drift.unload()` on `componentWillUnmount`. Then instead of wrapping the whole app with it, you drop it only in the home page, in a way it will be unmounted when you navigate to another section.

The other option, since you mentioned React Router, would be to watch the `location` of the app, either using `history.listen` - https://github.com/ReactTraining/history - or checking the props provided by React Router - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location - on `componentWillUpdate`, then turning driftbot on and off based on the current url.

Comment: The only issue with this, in regards to `.unload()` is that after calling it I am unable to call `.load()` successfully. But, `.load()` works the first time it is called. So it looks like `.unload()` is actually completely removing the script all together. I dont know

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, I didn't realise that was the actual problem. I have no knowledge of driftbot APIs. You should probably ask their support how to properly stop/start their widget in an SPA, but you could try `window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt = undefined` right before calling `driftbot_function();`